# Conflict warning after rename the form

Tags: c#, winforms, warnings

In my first project, I encountered this warning many times. After reading the warning description, I don't know exactly what it is and how to fix it. I think it occurs when I change the name of winform(.cs file). Please let me know what is the cause of this warning and how to fix it?
Thanks for your help.

> Warning   1   **The type** 'Patience_Management.med' in
>   'C:\Users\TNhan\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Patience_Management\Patience_Management\Class1.cs'
>   **conflicts with the imported type** 'Patience_Management.med' in
>   'c:\Users\TNhan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\Patience_Management\Patience_Management\bin\Debug\Patience_Management.exe'.
>   **Using the type defined in** 'C:\Users\TNhan\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Patience_Management\Patience_Management\Class1.cs'. C:\Users\TNhan\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects\Patience_Management\Patience_Management\kham.cs 17  9   Patience_Management

Maybe this image helps. The warning message appear at the green underline. 
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/a58e0.png

Comment: Sound to me like you added a reference to your own program.  Use Build + Clean to make that a permanent error.  Open the References node and remove the reference to fix.

Comment: I posted the class containing the warning message. Hope it helps –

Comment: It is exactly as I guessed, the Patient_Management project has a reference to Patient_Management.  Second item in the References list.  Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have two types with the same name.  Rename one of them, clean the solution, and rebuild.

Comment: I posted the class containing the warning message. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will fix the problem, but you should not use the same name for an object instance as the name of the object itself.  In your screenshot, you're using:

```
addPatience addPatience = new addPatience(TextBox1.Text);
```

as well as

```
kham kham = new kham // rest of line ommitted
```

Without trying it myself, I'm not sure that would even compile, and if it did you might have run-time issues.  At the very least, it would be confusing to read for any developer that would have to maintain your code.

Remember, C# is case-sensitive.